HierarchyID: Get all descendants for a list of parents using LINQ-to-SQL
I need to find all descendants for a given list of parents. The query (in plain SQL) was easy enough, but I can't translate it into LINQ-to-SQL.
SQL Query:
select child.id from GlobalDocumentClassification child 
  inner join GlobalDocumentClassification parent 
on child.HierarchyId.IsDescendantOf(parent.HierarchyId) = CAST(1 AS bit) and 
  parent.Id in ('5bb9450f-3778-411d-bbf2-5a5775c70310')

Here my (flawed) LINQ query:
var entityIds =
    from child in Context.GlobalDocumentClassification
    join parent in Context.GlobalDocumentClassification
        on child.HierarchyId.IsDescendantOf(child.HierarchyId) equals true
    where EF.Constant(documentClassificationIds).Contains(parent.Id)
        select child.Id;

The IDE complains about the use of parent - I believe this is related to how the LINQ-to-SQL queries need to be structured .
This SO article describes the SQL side of the problem a bit more detailed, but again I do need to express my query with LINQ. Linq to SQL: How to join on no field i.e. cartesian join
Your help is much appreciated


One of these questions might be relevant. The answer likely depends on your ORM.  I suggest that you add the relevant ORM and DBMS tags.

The LINQ join..on..equals clause doesn't have access to both enumerators simultaneously, it rather computes a key for each collection before independent of one another. What you want is a second from clause followed by a where. Ie from parent in Context.GlobalDocumentClassification where    child.HierarchyId.IsDescendantOf(child.HierarchyId). Remember LINQ is not SQL and the worst way of learning it is trying transliterate an existing SQL query

I think this can also be formulated as from child in Context.GlobalDocumentClassification where Context.GlobalDocumentClassification.Any(parent => child.HierarchyId.IsDescendantOf(parent.HierarchyId)) ....

Is this really LINQ-to-SQL (the ORM)? If it's Entity Framework then please revise the tags.

Did some more digging and found the following solution
var selfJoin = 
    from child in Context.GlobalDocumentClassification
    from parent in Context.GlobalDocumentClassification
    select new { child, parent };

var query = from item in selfJoin
    where item.child.HierarchyId.IsDescendantOf(item.parent.HierarchyId) &&
        EF.Constant(ids).Contains(item.parent.Id)
    select item.child.Id;


This produces SQL-Server cross join query and allows for the use of IsDescendantOf() in the queries where clause.
